# Как сохранить предыдущее состояние компонента в React-Native?

Tags: react-native

Добрый день, я новичок в React-Native и столкнулся с проблемой которую не нашел как решить или не знаю как точно задать вопрос

У меня есть компонент с профилем пользователя в нем есть дочерний компонент который показывает список людей подписанных на пользователя, нажав на подписчика можно перейти в его профайл, но если нажать кнопку назад то уже будет отображаться список подписчиков пользователя на которого мы перешли! Причина этому использование одного и того же компонента для отображения данных пользователя и списка подписчиков. Есть ли способ сохранить предыдущее состоянии?

Я использую React-native-route-flux для навигации, а для управление состояниями React-Redux

Это компонент списка пользователей

```
class Followers extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    const {uid} = this.props.user;
    this.props.followersFetch({uid});
    this.createDataSource(this.props)
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.createDataSource(nextProps)
  }

  createDataSource({followersList}) {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    })
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(followersList)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("GO TO UNMOUNT", this.props);

  }

  renderRow(info) {
    return (
      <User follower = {info} />
    );

  }

  render() {
    return (

      <Container>
          <Content>
              <ListView
              enableEmptySections
              dataSource={this.dataSource}
              renderRow={this.renderRow}
              />
          </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const  mapStateToProps = state  => {
  const followersList = state.followers;
  return {followersList}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {followersFetch})(Followers);
```

С помощью экшона получаю список пользователей!

Answer (score 0):

в actionType передай POP_AND_REPLACE

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]